# Get loginName of an UserProfile object

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an UserProfile object for the user john.

His LoginName is company\john.

i'm able to get it by objUserProfile["AccountName"].Value;

Now, i want to get details from the SPWeb object using this account name. but i'm unable to get it. Because in sharepoint the login name for that user is 
i#w:company\john. As i have enabled windows and farm-based authentication in my webapp, it is showing the loginname as i#w:company\john. But in userprofile object it is showing only company\john. What is the right way to access the details from sharepoint. 
Any suggestion please ..

Answer (score 5):

You can convert claim format into login name with:

```
string userName = null;
SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (mgr != null)
{
    userName = mgr.DecodeClaim(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName).Value;
}
```

and convert login name into claim format with:

```
string userName = null;
SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (mgr != null)
{
    SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.UserLogonName, "myuser", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string", SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.Forms, "myprovider"));
    userName = mgr.EncodeClaim(claim);
}
```

[Source](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/programmatically-converting-login-name-claim/)

More details of the SPClaimProviderManager from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee551344.aspx).

Comment: thats one crazy class I didn't know it existed... Nice one :)

Comment: +1 - this has been frustrating me for about an hour. I thought I'd have to start regex'ing the bloody thing out!